# Why is not the style tag applying here

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style the html code but  the css of style tag inside the const htmlContent is not applying to the html code below.Is there any other alternate way to do this which is easier .No styles are working

```
const htmlContent = `
    <style>
        table tr:hover {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    </style>
    
    <header style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;position: relative">
        <div class="contact-info" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 21px; margin-right: 25px; top: 0; right: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #fff; text-align: right;">
            Contact: +91-8491064038, +91-9622259639<br>
            Email: info@azeestravels.com
        </div>
        <div style ="padding: 20px;text-align: center;background-color: #333;">
            <h1 style="display: inline-block;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; color: #333; text-shadow: 2px 2px #ccc; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffcc00, #ff6600); -webkit-background-clip: text; -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;">Azees Travel</h1>
            <p id="tag" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: white; font-weight: bold;">Dream it, visit it</p></div>
        <div>
        <p id = "greet" style="font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 2.5; max-width: 1232px; padding: 30px; background-color: #fff; color: #333; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); margin: 0; margin-top: 10px;"><span id="gretD" style="font-size:29px">
            Greetings from Azees Travel!</span><br>
            Great to hear you are interested in visiting Kashmir.You can take a look at our scheduled upcoming tour for you. All of our Kashmir Tours include visits to Pahalgam, Gulmarg, 
            Sonamarg and Srinagar.It also includes accommodation and transfers, when you arrive from airport and depart to Airport.We use quality accommodation throughout the tour and make 
            use of new air-conditioned 4-wheelers. You are in good hands with our certified speaking guides all of whom work for us full time.We guarantee every tour and are committed to 
            making sure you have a great experience. We wish you a very happy journey and we would love to make your trip more comfortable and enjoyable.Team AZEES TRAVEL wishes you a great 
            journey & we would love to hear from you upon final package confirmation.
            Thank you .....!</p>
        </div>
        <h3 style="text-align:left;color: red; text-decoration: underline;">Summary:</h3>
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #f8f8f8; font-size: 16px; color: #333;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;"><Tour Duration:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">5 Days</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">Adults:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">Tour Start Date:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">April 1, 2023</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">Kids:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h3 style="text-align:left;color: red; text-decoration: underline;">The Travel Itinerary:</h3>
    </header>


    </form>`;
```

Comment: your markup seems invalid - where is the opening `form` tag?

Comment: Probably `td`s are covering the entire container `tr` and you just can't see the row changing the background color.

Comment: @Teemu I checked that, and you are right. OP should try `table tr:hover td { background-color: #f5f5f5; }`

Comment: `<style>` within the body is invalid since the `scope` attribute has been deprecated (8 years ago). Also, you should not mix head style with inline style. In 2023 style changes should be applied by CSS. Alternatively, you should consider the usage of Web-Components and adding the styles with the Shadow-DOM.

Comment: @Konrad still nt wrkng

Comment: @EssaMohammad You've to remove the inline styles from the cells, inline style has greater specifity (that makes styles [cascading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade)). Include the cell style in the style tag too, and insert the tag in the head section instead of body.

Comment: You have a lot of inline styles - is that because you are formatting for email?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You don't see the color change because `td` is in front `tr` and obscures the background
2. Inline style have higher specificity and will always override styles (so it's not recommended to use them)

Fix:

```
table tr:hover td {
  background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
```

Adding `td` fixes the obscuring problem

Adding `!important` fixes the inline style issue

```js
const htmlContent = `
    <style>
        table tr:hover td {
        background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    }
    </style>
    
    <header style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;position: relative">
        <div class="contact-info" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 21px; margin-right: 25px; top: 0; right: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #fff; text-align: right;">
            Contact: +91-8491064038, +91-9622259639<br>
            Email: info@azeestravels.com
        </div>
        <div style ="padding: 20px;text-align: center;background-color: #333;">
            <h1 style="display: inline-block;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; color: #333; text-shadow: 2px 2px #ccc; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffcc00, #ff6600); -webkit-background-clip: text; -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;">Azees Travel</h1>
            <p id="tag" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: white; font-weight: bold;">Dream it, visit it</p></div>
        <div>
        <p id = "greet" style="font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 2.5; max-width: 1232px; padding: 30px; background-color: #fff; color: #333; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); margin: 0; margin-top: 10px;"><span id="gretD" style="font-size:29px">
            Greetings from Azees Travel!</span><br>
            Great to hear you are interested in visiting Kashmir.You can take a look at our scheduled upcoming tour for you. All of our Kashmir Tours include visits to Pahalgam, Gulmarg, 
            Sonamarg and Srinagar.It also includes accommodation and transfers, when you arrive from airport and depart to Airport.We use quality accommodation throughout the tour and make 
            use of new air-conditioned 4-wheelers. You are in good hands with our certified speaking guides all of whom work for us full time.We guarantee every tour and are committed to 
            making sure you have a great experience. We wish you a very happy journey and we would love to make your trip more comfortable and enjoyable.Team AZEES TRAVEL wishes you a great 
            journey & we would love to hear from you upon final package confirmation.
            Thank you .....!</p>
        </div>
        <h3 style="text-align:left;color: red; text-decoration: underline;">Summary:</h3>
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #f8f8f8; font-size: 16px; color: #333;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;"><Tour Duration:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">5 Days</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">Adults:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">Tour Start Date:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">April 1, 2023</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">Kids:</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #e6e6e6; font-weight: bold;">8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h3 style="text-align:left;color: red; text-decoration: underline;">The Travel Itinerary:</h3>
    </header>


    </form>`;

document.body.innerHTML = htmlContent
```

Answer (score 0):

as the comments implied, the td was missing. But also add the !important to the css, otherwise it won't overwrite your background-color used in the table

```
<style>
        table tr:hover td {
        background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    }
    </style>
```